# Aliasing calculation result, grouping, and summing in ActiveRecord query using Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to calculate the total value of each `OrderItem` by multiplying the `unit_price` by the `quantity` and subtracting the `line_discount`, and then grouping by the `product_id` and summing the `line_total` so I can get the total line totals for each product.

I tried this first:

```
OrderItem.select("order_items.*, 
order_items.unit_price * order_items.quantity - order_items.line_discount AS line_total 
GROUP BY product_id").sum('line_total')
```

but I got this error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "line_total" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(line_total) AS sum_line_total, product_id...
             ^
: SELECT SUM(line_total) AS sum_line_total, product_id AS product_id FROM "order_items" GROUP BY product_id
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "line_total" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(line_total) AS sum_line_total, product_id...
```

I found a few questions on here where the answers suggested that wrapping the aliasing part of the query in a subquery was the solution, but I tried several variations on this and kept getting the same error.

Some of the variations with subqueries I tried:

```
OrderItem.select("order_items.*, 
(SELECT order_items.unit_price * order_items.quantity - order_items.line_discount AS line_total 
GROUP BY order_items.product_id)").sum('line_total')

OrderItem.select("order_items.*, 
(SELECT unit_price * quantity - line_discount AS line_total 
FROM order_items GROUP BY order_items.product_id)").sum('line_total')

OrderItem.select("order_items.*, 
(SELECT order_items.unit_price * order_items.quantity - order_items.line_discount AS line_total)")
.group(:product_id).sum("line_total")
```

How can I adjust this query to return the result I'm looking for?

Comment: @test Thank you, but it's not working.  I should've posted that as another variation I tried, but I removed the parens when they didn't seem to help with any of the variations.  In case it's useful, I edited my question with the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to give up selecting all the fields (which you probably don't want anyway, since you're just grouping by `product_id`), this query will do it for you:

```
OrderItem.group("product_id").sum("unit_price * quantity - line_discount")
```

The result will be a hash, where the keys are product_ids and the values are the sums.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm looking for!  I tried something similar early on but it wasn't working.  I wish I could find it so I knew what the difference was, but regardless, this gives me the result I need.  Thank you!